# Jsr223 sampler sending null json to kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, jmeter, jsr223

I am using jsr223 sampler to post json message to kafka using kafka client jar. When I am posting message is going in kafka as null. Can someone tell what I am missing.  Actually  message is going as null in Application .Below is my code.

```html
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.header.Header;
import org.apache.kafka.common.header.internals.RecordHeader;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterVariables;


Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("bootstrap.servers", "lxkfkbkomsstg01.lowes.com:9093,lxkfkbkomsstg02.lowes.com:9093,lxkfkbkomsstg03.lowes.com:9093,lxkfkbkomsstg04.lowes.com:9093,lxkfkbkomsstg05.lowes.com:9093");
props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
props.put("compression.type", "none");
props.put("batch.size", "16384");
props.put("linger.ms", "0");
props.put("buffer.memory", "33554432");
props.put("acks", "1");
props.put("send.buffer.bytes", "131072");
props.put("receive.buffer.bytes", "32768");
props.put("security.protocol", "SSL");
//props.put("sasl.kerberos.service.name", "kafka");
//props.put("sasl.mechanism", "GSSAPI");
//props.put("ssl.keystore.type", "JKS");
props.put("ssl.truststore.location", "/Users/rajkumar/Documents/EOMS/eoms-truststore-stage.jks");
props.put("ssl.truststore.password", "4DxYJnVDcPi6E8w3uCS63qoa");
props.put("ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm", "");
props.put("ssl.protocol", "SSL");
props.put("ssl.truststore.type", "JKS");

String eventType="orbit_pick";

KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(props);
List<Header> headers = new ArrayList<Header>();
    Header header = new RecordHeader("event_type",eventType.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    headers.add(header);
//        headers.add(new RecordHeader("event_type",eventType.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));

Date latestdate = new Date();
ProducerRecord<String, String> producerRecord = new ProducerRecord<String, String>("orbit.shipment.lfs.inbound.prf", 1, latestdate.getTime(), "702807441", "{\"SellerOrganizationCode\":\"LOWES\",\"ShipNode\":\"0224\",\"IsShortage\":\"N\",\"ShipmentKey\":\"2022021708351092902896763\",\"ShipmentNo\":\"702807441\",\"Extn\":{\"ExtnPickingHasStartedFlag\":\"Y\",\"ExtnSourceSystem\":\"StoreOrderSvc\",\"ExtnPickerId\":\"98977\",\"ExtnOperation\":\"pick\",\"ExtnInPickupLocker\":\"N\"},\"Instructions\":{\"Instruction\":{\"InstructionText\":\"picking\"},\"Replace\":\"Y\"},\"ShipmentLines\":{\"ShipmentLine\":[{\"BackroomPickedQuantity\":\"1\",\"Quantity\":\"3\",\"CodeValue\":\"\",\"ShipmentLineNo\":\"1\",\"ShipmentSubLineNo\":\"0\",\"ShortageQty\":\"\",\"ItemID\":\"1505\",\"NewShipNode\":\"\",\"Extn\":null}]},\"MessageID\":\"8970549709qqaachwejhk\",\"MessageTimeStamp\":\\"${__time(yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss)}\",\"eventType\":\"orbit_multiple_shipments_customer_pickup\"}", headers);

producer.send(producerRecord);
producer.close();
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Added my code. Can you check what I am missing. I am trying to post message with header. JSON I am trying to post as sting but its going as null.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any code so it's expected it doesn't send anything to Kafka.

Here is some sample you can use as a reference:

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord

def props = new Properties()
props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
props.put("acks", "all")
props.put("retries", 0)
props.put("batch.size", 16384)
props.put("linger.ms", 1)
props.put("buffer.memory", 33554432)
props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")

def producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props)

producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>("your-topic", "your-key", "your-json-here"))

producer.close()
```

P.S. Are you aware of [Pepper-Box - Kafka Load Generator](https://github.com/GSLabDev/pepper-box) plugin? You may find it easier to configure and use. Check out [Apache Kafka - How to Load Test with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-kafka-how-to-load-test-with-jmeter) article for more information

Comment: Added my code in my question. Can you check what is the issue.